# Problems with Sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, sorcery

I'm running into multiple problems..

1.When I start up the rails server and visit `http://0.0.0.0:3000/users`, I am able to see all users which is what I want however, when I click on the login button, enter in my credentials, and try to login I'm greeted with this page..

```
No route matches [POST] "/user_sessions/new"
```

I'm confused since I am already on the new.html.erb page?

2.I am using the sorcery and simple_form gem and I ran

```
rails generate scaffold User username:string email:string crypted_password:string salt:string
```

but now I have two migration files in db/migrate and I am not sure which one I need to keep since I have a user_sessions controller and a users controller?

All of my source code is available at https://bitbucket.org/jasonriddle/stubmoney

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. this is embarrassing.. This..

```
resources :users
resources :user_sessions

match 'login'  => 'user_sessions#new',     :as => :login
match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
```

Is not the same as this..

```
match 'login'  => 'user_sessions#new',     :as => :login
match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup

resources :users
resources :user_sessions
```

Could someone explain why the ordering matters?

Also, when I enter my credentials and hit the login button, the new page is rendered again..

Answer (score 0):

From "Rails Routing from the Outside In":

**The routes.rb file is processed from top to bottom when a request comes in. The request will be dispatched to the first matching route. If there is no matching route, then Rails returns HTTP status 404 to the caller.**

Not sure why you are getting the page rendered again.